# Having trouble increasing WordPress memory limit on nginx server

Tags: php, nginx, wordpress, php-fpm, openbsd

I am trying to increase the memory limit on my nginx php-fpm server for wordpress. Specifically the Wordpress plugin WooCommerce needs more available memory.

I've set the following in wp-config.php...

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');
define('WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');
```

php.ini has the following...

```
memory_limit = 128M
;suhosin.memory_limit = 0
```

The fpm server is also set to change this.

```
php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 128M
```

Yet WooCommerce's system status still claims it only has 40MB, how can this be?

I believe it might be suhosin but I am unsure how to change this on an OpenBSD server. I've tried changing it in the settings for the php-fpm server pool.

```
php_admin_value[suhosin.memory_limit] = 128M
```

If someone can tell me how to change the limit on an OpenBSD server that would be very good.

Comment: Did you restart php-fpm?

Comment: Yes I restarted php-fpm.

Comment: Could you post the contents of `wp-config.php` file, __excluding__ DB credentials, salt, and table_prefix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can not re-define a *constant* (in PHP / WordPress). So, you must have put the line...

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');
```

at the **end** of your *wp-config.php* file. If you are not already aware, the last default line in this file (`require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');`) setup all the variables and constants.

In order to solve your issue, you must define 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT' **before** WordPress sets its constants. So, the contents (or `tail wp-config.php`) of your site's `wp-config.php` file should read like this...

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M' );

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Basically, there is nothing wrong with Nginx or php-fpm. The issue is in *where you define a constant for WordPress*.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can remember, Wordpress doesn't list available/maximum RAM but allowed upload file size.

You can change that through the `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` settings in php.ini or per-pool in your php-fpm.d/*.conf files.

Concerning nginx, remember to set `client_max_body_size 128m;` to allow for bigger POST data to be sent to/through the webserver.

Comment: This has nothing to do with upload size. The Wordpress plugin WooCommerce lists available memory on it's system status page. I need to increase the max memory.

Comment: What happens if you go crazy and set memory_limit to 512M or something like that? Make sure there isn't a [per-directory php.ini file](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) in effect, overriding the main config. Try momentarily disabling APC as it can show you stale/cached PHP output.

Comment: I don't seem to have APC installed so it isn't that. There is no php.ini for the users directory.

Comment: I definitely don't have APC, just confirmed that.